# My Website is not secure from a link but is from browser

Tags: http, security, https, mobile-website

I recently made a website for freelance web design and am hosting it through GitHub and renting a domain name from GoDaddy. The site is HTTPS and the developer tools show no security issues. When I click a link to it on my laptop, the connection is secure. However, when I click the same link on my phone (iPhone XR), it says that the connection is not secure. When I check the URL, it is HTTPS.

Does anyone know why this may be happening?

Also, am I allowed to put the link to my website in my question, or is that against the rules (for like self-promotion or something).

Thanks!

Comment: you need to show us the website link you are using.

Comment: What I suspect is happening is the text says `https://www.website.com` but the actual HTML anchor link may be going to somewhere else `http://www.forwarder-service.com/website?visit=website.com` for example

Comment: https://www.hodgeswebdevelopment.com. I figured out something. with www it works, but not without. I believe this is because under the CNAME file on github, it has www. If I change it to just hodgeswebdevelopment.com, only without www works. Is there a way to make both versions of the domain work securely?

Update: Now it's really weird with CNAME being www.hodgeswebdevelopment.com. No matter what I type in, with or without www or https://, it changes to hodgeswebdevelopment.com. When I click on the URL at the top, it shows a red https with a line through it

Comment: Whoever issues your SSL/TLS certificate has only done so for one domain. Contact them to cover the other domain as well.

Comment: Or simply don't use www. and only use the base name domain.

Comment: Ok so I changed everything to just the base (there were a few spots I forgot) and added a CNAME to godaddy for my github pages URL. I believe that fixed it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The Github documentation might be useful here: https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.1/admin/configuration/configuring-network-settings/configuring-tls

Comment: Ok your web link now works correctly for me `:-)`